# Eigenvalue problem with boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-differences

I am playing with the one dimensional massless Dirac equation
$$-i\partial_x \sigma_x \Psi(x) = \epsilon \Psi(x) \, .$$ Solving it analytically with some boundary conditions is an easy task. I am more interested in the numerical approach. One can rewrite the equation in matrix form using finite symmetric difference and obtain.

$$M\Psi = V$$
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
-t & -\epsilon & t & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -t & -\epsilon & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -t & -\epsilon & t \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ $$t = -i\sigma_x/2a$$ $$\Psi=(\Psi_1, \Psi_2, \dots, \Psi_N)^{T}$$
$$V=(\Psi_0, 0, \dots, 0, \Psi_L)^{T}$$
Where the boundary conditions are implemented $\Psi(0) = \Psi_0$ and $\Psi(L)=\Psi_L$.
Here I am stuck. How can I proceed to calculate the energies and corresponding wavefunction?